# SQL Join on 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is my query:

```
select custnmbr,custname,slprsnid,cdatetime,cdur,cnumber,cext,
finalcalledpartynumber,sono,invno,ordamt,invamt,adduser
from table1 calls left join table2 cust 
on (calls.number = cust.phone1 or calls.cext = cust.phone1)   
left outer join table3 sales on (cust.custnmbr = sales.custno 
and sales.adddate = @date)
where (cnumber = @phone or cext = @phone) and cdatetime >= @date
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

Get all the calls from table 1, and get the customer from table 2. Then get all the sales from table 3 and the customer from table 2.

What I am getting is all the calls, the customer, and then if there is an order for that customer I get that as well. What I want is all the orders as well.

Just looking for some pointers on joining 3 tables.

Comment: It would help to provide some sample data and expected result

Comment: That would help. the question isn't very clear.

Comment: What would also help is adding the table aliases to all the columns used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about how you're going to handle the calls and sales results since there does not appear to be a correlation between calls and sales. So, a customer with 3 calls and 4 sales will produce 12 rows in the result set. *This is where we could help you better if you provide more specifics.*

The concept is that if calls is a necessary requirement, then you could do something like...

```
SELECT  ca.CallId, ca.TimeStarted, ...,
        c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, ...,
        s.SaleDate, s.SaleAmount, ...
FROM    calls AS ca
        INNER JOIN customers AS c ON ca.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
        OUTER APPLY (   --or CROSS APPLY, depending on your needs
            SELECT  s.SaleDate, s.SaleAmount, ...
            FROM    sales AS s
            WHERE   s.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
                    AND s.SaleDate = ca.CallDate  --It would help if this relationship existed
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would start with the table you want ALL the data from, the one that you are going to form the basis of your navigation to the other entities.:

```
SELECT 
  C.*,
  Ca.*,
  S.*
FROM Sales S
LEFT JOIN Customer C
  ON (S.CustomerId = C.CustomerId) -- your condition
LEFT JOIN Calls Ca
  ON (C.CustomerId = Ca.CustomerId) -- your condition
```